# Accordion does not work when loaded later via Ajax

Tags: javascript

here is my javascript Accordion code,i use multi-label accordion . first label work but does not work 2nd or 3rd label ,when i click first label accordion it does not expand  .I bring in the content for the accordion dynamically using AJAX . mainly i wont show data dynamically when insert or update any data from admin panel by using setTimeInterval.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">



        var multisidetabs=(function(){
             var opt,parentid,
          vars={
            listsub:'.list-sub',
            showclass:'mg-show'
          },
          test=function(){
            console.log(parentid);
          },
          events = function(){
            $(parentid).find('a').on('click',function(ev){
              ev.preventDefault();
              var atag = $(this), childsub = atag.next(vars.listsub);
              //console.log(atag.text());
              if(childsub && opt.multipletab == true){
                if(childsub.hasClass(vars.showclass)){
                  childsub.removeClass(vars.showclass).slideUp(500);
                }else{
                  childsub.addClass(vars.showclass).slideDown(500);
                }
              }
              if(childsub && opt.multipletab == false){
               childsub.siblings(vars.listsub).removeClass(vars.showclass).slideUp(500);
               if(childsub.hasClass(vars.showclass)){
                 childsub.removeClass(vars.showclass).slideUp(500);
               }else{
                 childsub.addClass(vars.showclass).slideDown(500);
               }
              }
            });
          },
          init=function(options){//initials
            if(options){
              opt = options;
              parentid = '#'+options.id;
              //test();
              events();
            }else{ alert('no options'); }
          }

            return {init:init};
        })();

        multisidetabs.init({
            "id":"mg-multisidetabs",
          "multipletab":false
        });

  // set time

  function loadDoc() {

$.ajax({

        url: "indexLoad.php",

        success: function (data) {
              v=data;
              $("#demo").html(data);

        }
    });

  return v;
```

}

```
setInterval(function () {
    loadDoc();
}, 100);
```

"

Comment: call accordion function within loadDoc method

Comment: i also try this but not wok

Comment: what is data in ?

Comment: multi-label accordian php data